# I need to report MoS2 values from Mo and Sulfur numbers

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, analytical-chemistry

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do this and yes, I have the molecular weights, just don't know how to calculate. Been 20 years since college.

EDIT: I'm working with Copper ores. One customer reported Mo% as 5.2, S% as 5.3. The other customer reports $\ce{MoS2}$ values (this particular one is 12.34%) I need to compare these values.

EDIT #2::  I need to report 5.2% Mo and 5.3% Sulfur as ONE value - As "MoS2" if that is possible.

Comment: What values? What numbers? Please, clarify a little more the question.

Comment: I'm working with Copper ores...  One customer reported Mo% as 5.2, S% as 5.3.  The other customer reports MoS2 values (this particular one is 12.34%)  I need to compare these values.  Thanks

Comment: I presume that's % by mass?

Comment: And now you want to calculate which perventage of 12.34 % belongs to m% Mo and which percentage belongs to m% S ?

Comment: No.  I need to report 5.2% Mo and 5.3% Sulfur as ONE value in terms of MoS2, so that I can compare it to the value that was reported by someone else (The 12.34% MoS2)

Comment: Is Mo or S in any other compounds in the sample besides MoS2?

Comment: So you want to find the percentage of MoS2 in the sample from the values told by the first customer and check whether it is equal to the value told by second customer?

Answer (score 2):

As the molecular mass of molybdenum is $95.95~\mathrm{g/mol} \approx 96~\mathrm{g/mol}$ and the molecular mass of sulfur is $32.06~\mathrm{g/mol} \approx 32~\mathrm{g/mol}$ one can construct a ratio between both molecular masses that in turn can be solved easily.
$$\frac{96~a}{32~b}=\frac{5.2}{5.3}=0.98\approx1$$
Which gives us after the multiplication with 32/96 on both sides
$$\frac{a}{b}=1\cdot\frac{32}{96}=\frac{1}{3}$$
So customer 1's determined "compound" is not $\ce{MoS2}$ but more $\ce{MoS3}$. Now I would guess that they don't analyze the copper ore for the compound $\ce{MoS2}$ but for both elements $\ce{Mo}$ and $\ce{S}$ separately which is why they came up with $5.2~\%~\ce{Mo}$ and $5.3~\%~\ce{S}$.

In my opinion, you should ask customer 2 to split up it's $12.34~\%~\ce{MoS2}$ into the percentages of each element and compare them with $5.2~\%$ and $5.3~\%$.

Using the ratio for $\ce{MoS2}$ which is $60:40$ one would estimate those $12.34~\%$ to split up into $7.40~\%~\ce{Mo}$ and $4.94~\%~\ce{S}$ or into $6.16~\%~\ce{Mo}$ and $6.18\%~\ce{S}$ if it is more like $\ce{MoS3}$.

---

Or to answer your question ... probably you can simply add both values to give you $10.5~\%$ which nonetheless will not be equal to $\ce{MoS2}$ based upon the data you are given!